# Html tag with id attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering what html tag that suppport id attribute either than `<p>` tag because i want to change the tag by javascript but i dont want it to be appear in paragraph.
This all what ive been trying

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    Name : <p id="user">user1</p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="Arvin";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but the result is

> Name :
>   Arvin

what I want is

> Name : Arvin

thanks for spending your time to read this..any help will much appreciated

Comment: what is the difference betweeen the two results you've mentienned?

Comment: Result and what you want are same ?

Comment: maybe the <p> dispaly is block ?

Comment: i mean 
result
name : 
arvin
arvin text shown in paragraph(under name: text) because of    <p>    tag

what i want is the arvin text to appear just next to name

Comment: @Alvin: see my response, it works like a chamrm

Answer (score 4):

Every tag supports `id`. In your case, `<span>` would work well.

```js
document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="Arvin";
```

```html
Name : <span id="user">user1</span>
```

Comment: Does not matter he can change css display:block; to display:inline-block.

Comment: Using a span for inline text is far more appropriate than changing paragraphs to be inline-block, even though both will work for the example.

Comment: Yes, he could. But why, when there's no semantic reason to use `p` here?

Comment: Of course if person wants he is king :). I mean it is possible use even p tag. By semantics it dose not matter. But polite way to use appropriate tag.

Comment: @PaulRoub if you know how browser work you will not say in this way. Because every element has default css preset for each element. The suggested answer is the best but there are alternatives every time. So you can use css in order to do this. Of course there is not doubt that it will make overhead for rendering page.

Comment: @PaulRoub can you explain why <span> works well? The quality of answer is not enough I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This code goes wrong because paragraph are shown into a new line (by browser).
This code put text in two lines (without your Javascript)

```
<html>
  <body>
    Name : <p id="user">user1</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You maybe shoud better do this:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <p>Name : <span id="user">user1</span></p>
  </body>
</html>

document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="Arvin";
```

See running example here:

Comment: Paragraph does not add return line. Information is misleading.

Comment: <p>line 1 </p><p>line2</p>

Comment: Carriage return character is \n but paragraph is rendered by browser in the way that it will occupy all horizontal space where positioning:static. In other positioning values rendering can be different.

Comment: I never talk of character. Let's say Show the paragraph in a new line? is ir better for you?

Comment: This code goes wrong because there always is paragraph are shown into a carriage return before the paragraph's text new line (by browser). This code put text in two lines (without your Javascript) <- This wat is you write in first place. Carriage return if it is not character what are you talking about?

Comment: Do not be aggressive I am helping to improve your answer for the question.

Comment: For sure, you can notice all my edits after your comment's ;-) English isn't my mothertongue so I take your advice ;-) I was thinking that carriage return ~= new line but no

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any tag that wouldn't support the `id` attribute, neither can the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes):

> 3.2.5 Global attributes
>
> The following attributes are common to and may be specified on all
>   HTML elements (even those not defined in this specification): ... id
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: inline` style in `<p>` tag  and your problem is solved. You can use id calling on any tag though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    Name : <p id="user" style="display:inline;">user1</p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("user").innerHTML="Arvin";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```